# issue handling paypal payment with php

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, superglobals

I have integrated paypal payments in my website
The system works like this (i'll post code below)
A user buys a suscription for 13€ , when he clicks he's redirected with php to paypal to complete the transaction , the issue is , on completion of the payment i have to do a update on the user privileges on mysql , i do that in the page of successful payment , the thing is if you load manually that page , you get the update on mysql and you have access.
This is the page that loads when the payment is successful

```
include ("../session.php");
$usuario = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$servername = "**";
$username = "**";
$password = "**";
$dbname = "**";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "UPDATE login SET premium=1 WHERE username='$usuario'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    //echo "Ahora ya eres premium";
    header('Location: ../ppv.php');

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

and this is where i do the payment and redirects

```
$servername = "**";
$username = "**";
$password = "**";
$dbname = "**";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$user= $_SESSION['login_user'];
$sql ="SELECT premium FROM login where username='$user'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {



    }
} else {
    echo "No hay registro";
}



$data=array(
'merchant_email'=>'**',
'product_name'=>'Pase premium',
'amount'=>13,
'currency_code'=>'EUR',
'thanks_page'=>"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/paypal/web/pago/exito.php',
'notify_url'=>"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'paypal/ipn.php',
'cancel_url'=>"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
'paypal_mode'=>true,
);
?>
<form id='paypal-info' method='post' action='#'>
<label>Nombre del producto : <?php echo $data['product_name']; ?></label></br>
<label>Precio : <?php echo $data['amount'].''.$data['currency_code']; ?></label>

<input type='submit' name='pay_now' id='pay_now' value='Pagar' />
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['pay_now'])){
echo Paypal($data);

}

function Paypal( $data) {

define( 'SSL_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' );
 define( 'SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' );

$action = '';
 //Is this a test transaction?
 $action = ($data['paypal_mode']) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_URL;

$form = '';

$form .= '<form name="frm_payment_method" action="' . $action . '" method="post">';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="' . $data['merchant_email'] . '" />';
 // Instant Payment Notification & Return Page Details /
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="' . $data['notify_url'] . '" />';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="' . $data['cancel_url'] . '" />';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="' . $data['thanks_page'] . '" />';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />';
 // Configures Basic Checkout Fields -->
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="" />';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />';
 // <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="localhost" />-->
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="' . $data['currency_code'] . '" />';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="paypal" />';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . $data['product_name'] . '" />';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd"/>';
 $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $data['amount'] . '" />';
 $form .= '<script>';
 $form .= 'setTimeout("document.frm_payment_method.submit()", 2);';
 $form .= '</script>';
 $form .= '</form>';
 return $form;
 }
?>
```

All of this is working properly if the user comes back to the website , which is the way i meant to do it.
The question is : how would you make sure that there's been a payment on the first code i posted

Comment: I was thinking of using some field on the form and using $_POST , but the user comes from paypal so those variables won't have any values. i mean like checking with an IF that that variable is set , and then executing the query

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE login SET premium=1 WHERE username='$usuario'";` this line can be very dangerous, considering the way that session var is set!

Comment: i guess you mean i should used prepared statements

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, but only if `$username` occurs to be an user input.

Comment: then no , $username is a variable that gets its value from a $_session global